# move cursor spark text input

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I am using flex 4.5
I am using spark.components.TextInput control.
The values of the text can be change dynamically according to user selection.
The problem is that after the user is write anythings the textInput and change the value of the text the cursor position return to the begining of the textInput so if the user wants to continue enter .text in textInput he first need to move the cursor to the end.

How can I control the cursor position ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that when the user selects something else, then selects the textInput, the cursor position is reset to the beginning of the the text input? I don't understand when exactly the problem happens.

Answer (score 1):

Hi hope I understood your problem correctly

**My workflow**:

- listen to the selectionChange event
- selectionAnchorPosition give you the last position
- store this position somewhere in a temp variable
- Something happen, and you put your cursor in the textfield where you want (button1_clickHandler)

**My code example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var pos:Number = 0;

            protected function textinput1_selectionChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                pos = TextInput(event.target).selectionAnchorPosition;
            }

            protected function button1_clickHandler(pos:Number):void
            {
                ti.setFocus();  
                ti.selectRange(pos,pos);            
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <s:TextInput id="ti" text="abces"  selectionChange="textinput1_selectionChangeHandler(event)"/>

    <s:Label  text="{'lastCursorPos ' + pos}"/>

    <s:Button label="Set pos 1" click="button1_clickHandler(1)" />
    <s:Button label="Set pos 5" click="button1_clickHandler(5)" />
    <s:Button label="Set pos 15" click="button1_clickHandler(15)" />
</s:Application>
```